# How can I access array element using javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
var j = 0;
for (j = 0; j < checkInUnit.length; j++) {

adjustArray.push([checkInUnit[j], totalCheckInUserPerUnit[j]]);
}
```

adjustArray output is 10,1,11,5,12,8,13,2,16,6,17,15,18,15,19,3

If I want to access 10, 11, 12,13,16,17,18  etc?

How can i access using javascript in above context.

Comment: Sort the array first.

Comment: Access how exactly? If you have the index, use brackets! And wouldn't you have an array filled with arrays ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if directly then you can go for

```
adjustArray[1] and so on
```

OR in loop then in the same way you did checkInUnit

```
for (j = 0; j < adjustArray.length; j++){
 console.log(adjustArray[j]);
}
```

I hope you get an idea...

Comment: What's the point here? This doesn't answer OP's question at all.

Comment: @Teemu he just wanted to get the way out (traverse the array) , I just gave the hint. Now he can implement his logic.

Comment: Looks like OP wants to access particular values in the array, not all of them: "`I want to access 10, 11, 12,13,16,17,18 etc.`"

Comment: yes, i just showed him the way to traverse. Logic will be "his", he can even go for "j=j+2" in "for" loop to get alternate values. Note : I treated it to be a single dimension array (adjustArray)

Answer (score 0):

You can access elements in an array with square brackets

```
var firstElement = adjustArray[0]; // note arrays always use 0 based indicies
```

You can work through each element with a for loop

```
for(var key in adjustArray){
  var thisElement = adjustArray[key];      
}
```

You have a nested array here so you'll want to do something like this

```
for(var key in adjustArray){
      for(var nestedkey in adjustArray[key]){
         var thisElement = adjustArray[key][nestedkey];
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you noticed, that OP has created a nested array? And please, don't use `for..in` to iterate arrays.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu, I'd not spotted - I've expanded